# Apache 2.4.10 with mod_rewrite returns '404 Not Found'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm locally developing a web service on Apache 2.4.10 (Debian).
I'd like to use the URLs as something like this one: http://localhost/ws/rest/users
where the /ws/rest are physical directories and users is a parameter.

I wrote the following /var/www/html/ws/rest/.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ws/rest/api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ws/rest/api.php [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ws/rest/api.php [QSA,NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

The idea is redirect all the inner paths to the api.php file but when i point the browser to the previous URL i always receive '404 Not found' error.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `RewriteBase` directive.

Since your `.htaccess` file is in your `/ws/rest/` directory and this path is part of your url you could use `/ws/rest/` as the `RewiteBase`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ws/rest/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

[RewriteBase documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)

Comment: Sorry, nothing changed, again 404. Is there a way to know if the rewrite is active? I have the rewrite.load in the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ directory ...

Comment: I checked in the 'Loaded modules' by phpinfo() and in apache_get_modules() list: both reported mod_rewrite enabled. I insert some garbage chars in the top of .htaccess file and again 404 error. Should I receive other error ????

Comment: you should. If you put a file `test.html` under `/var/www/html/test.html` can you access it with http://localhost/test.html ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved adding to the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

and restarted apache